# Difference between "you're such a" and "you're a"

Tags: word-usage

I wonder if my example below is correct or if it needs to say "you're such a" instead of just "you're a" of course I wanted it to sound funny as a joke not as a real thing.

My friend: "You know me du!"

Me: I kinda do dawg, you're a hustler!"

Further info. I read on a web page that "such" can be followed by adjective + noun, judgemental noun or just plain noun, but I don't know if I really need the use of "such" for a statement such as my example. Below is the link for the webpage, mentioned before.

Link: http://www.curso-ingles.com/aprender/cursos/nivel-avanzado/adjectives-and-adverbs/so-vs-such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the pattern in your example

> I kinda do dawg, you're a hustler!

The usually pattern is

> you're **such** a hustler!

**such** being used as a superlative expressing a "high degree" or being "exemplary" of an *adjective*.

Being "such a hustler" is having more "hustle" than just being "a hustler".

> you're such a worry wort  *( worry about everything )*
>   you're such a baby  *( cries when doesn't get their way )*
>   you're such a whiner  *( big complainer )*

Comment: I see what you mean, I like your answer. Specially the pattern part, it explains a lot. I should have written that to mean that he is really hustling.